# Why does select only show file descriptors as ready if data is already being sent?

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming, synchronous

I'm using select() in a thread to monitor a datagram socket, but unless data is being sent to the socket before the thread starts, select() will continue to return 0.

I'm mixing a little C and C++; here's the method that starts the thread:

```
bool RelayStart() {
    sock_recv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    memset(&addr_recv, 0, sizeof(addr_recv));
    addr_recv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr_recv.sin_port = htons(18902);
    addr_recv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    bind(sock_recv, (struct sockaddr*) &addr_recv, sizeof(addr_recv));

    isRelayingPackets = true;

    NSS::Thread::start(VIDEO_SEND_THREAD_ID);

    return true;
}
```

The method that stops the thread:

```
bool RelayStop() {
    isSendingVideo = false;
    NSS::Thread::stop();
    close(sock_recv);
    return true;
}
```

And the method run in the thread:

```
void Run() {

    fd_set read_fds;
    int select_return;
    struct timeval select_timeout;

    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(sock_recv, &read_fds);

    while (isRelayingPackets) {

        select_timeout.tv_sec = 1;
        select_timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        select_return = select(sock_recv + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &select_timeout);
        if (select_return > 0 && FD_ISSET(sock_recv, &read_fds)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if there isn't a process already sending UDP packets to port 18902 before RelayStart() is called, select() will always return 0.  So, for example, I can't restart the sender without restarting the thread (in the correct order.)

Everything seems to work fine as long as the sender is started first.

Comment: Did you verify that `socket()` and `bind()` are not reporting errors?  Your code has no error checking in it.  Also, try including an exception `fd_set` when calling `select()` in case the socket is reportiing errors while your thread is running.

Comment: Errors don't show up in the exception set, oddly enough, but in the read set; only out of band data shows up in the exception set.

Comment: I should have mentioned that while I didn't have any robust error checking, I was watching the return value of select(), which was consistently 0 (non-error.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Run` thread only constructs `read_fds` once.

The `select` call updates `read_fds` to have all its bits cleared for all descriptors that did not have data ready, and all its bits set for those that were set before and do have data ready.

Hence, if no descriptor has any data ready and the `select` call times out (and returns 0), all the bits in `read_fds` are now cleared.  Further calls passing the same all-zero bit-mask will scan no file descriptors.

You can either re-construct the read-set on each trip inside the loop:

```
while (isRelayingPackets) {
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_SET(sock_recv, &read_fds);
    ...
}
```

or use an auxiliary variable with a copy of the bit-set:

```
while (isRelayingPackets) {
    fd_set select_arg = read_fds;
    ... same as before but use &select_arg ...
}
```

(Or, of course, there are non-`select` interfaces that are easier to use in some ways.)

Comment: Ah ha, I missed this detail in the manual: "On exit (from select), the sets are modified in place to indicate which file descriptors actually changed status."  The FD_ISSET() macro exists to determine if an FD is part of the changed set.  Thanks!  Any chance you could briefly list the non-select interfaces, so I can look them up and do some reading?

Comment: The easy (?) one is `poll`; the fancy and efficient but Linux-specific one for huge descriptor sets is `epoll`; the BSDs have `kqueue`.

Comment: I'm familiar with poll and epoll and considered them; I can't remember why I chose select instead.  I'll look over them again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How were you expecting it to behave?  The point of `select()` is to sleep to a timeout until data are available to be read; in this case, it will time out after 1 second and return 0.  Perhaps you don't actually want a timeout before the start of a stream?

Comment: Duke is saying that data is being sent but `select()` is not reporting it.  I would suspect a problem with the socket itself before I would suspect a problem with `select()`, though.

Comment: Remy is correct; I was trying to be clear that data is in fact being sent while select() is being called.